# Read barcode via USB scanner then send it to database

Tags: wifi, usb, mysql

I need to read some barcodes from 10 different working stations, unfortunately I can't put a PC on every station because the space is really small.

Given the little space I have I would like to use Rasberry Pi to handle it.

This is how the process should work:

1. Read barcode via USB scanner connected to Rasberry Pi
2. Send code to a MySQL database on my server using WiFi
3. Run a little application on my server that check the new barcodes and handles it.

This is just the basic but do you think this is doable ?

Comment: It's absolutely possible. Go for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason it would not.

Just be careful about the connection between Pi and server, as the messages might need to be queued in order to not lose packets when there are too many at once.

I suggest sending [JSON-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) messages to your server to easily include additional data like the source (workstation #) or a timestamp along your actual barcode.

The json messages as well as the MySQL database are predestinated for web server communication, which would be easy on both ends (your server and the pis), since there are endless ressources available but it is by no means necessary to take that route.

Other than that it is unclear what you need help with, so please edit your question if you do need specific assistance. I will try my best to alter my answer accordingly.